# How to use Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula(BBP formular) Step by step

Tags: pi

From this link [BBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) I want to know how BBP formula exactly work.

And i need simple example. Maybe find 3th or 5th digit of pi.
I am not good at math,i think step by step solution good for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you aware that the BBP formula doesn't find decimal digits of pi, but rather hexadecimal digits?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes,but there are anyway to convert hexadecimal digits to decimal digit?.If you have other way or other formula please show me. Thank you for reply.

Comment: The whole clue is that you compute **only isolated** hex digits, e.g. the hex digit at position $10^9$ not the complete base-16 representation up to $10^9.$
There is no way to transform this into an isolated decimal digit.